# Accessing sublists conditional on their length

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list that looks like this:

```
list = {{{151.335`, 245.102`}, {1, 1}}, {{41.435`, 245.021`}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, 
{{131.048`, 243.364`}, {3, 3}, {56, 56}, {76, 23}}, {{164.911`, 244.039`}, {4, 4}}, 
{{98.1685`, 239.618`}, {5, 5}}, {{196.333`, 239.212`}, {6, 6}}, {{184.767`, 234.228`},
 {7, 7}}, {{213.044`, 234.24`}, {8, 8}}, {{26.6316`, 221.423`}, {9, 9}}};
```

How can I return the last element in each sublist conditional on the sublist being a critical length `k`?  For example if we set `k=3`, we'd return `{{3, 3}, {76, 23}}` from the above list.

Here's the naive way to do it:

```
k = 3;

list = {{{151.335`, 245.102`}, {1, 1}}, {{41.435`, 245.021`}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, 
        {{131.048`, 243.364`}, {3, 3}, {56, 56}, {76, 23}}, {{164.911`, 244.039`}, 
         {4, 4}}, {{98.1685`, 239.618`}, {5, 5}}, {{196.333`, 239.212`}, {6, 6}}, 
        {{184.767`, 234.228`}, {7, 7}}, {{213.044`, 234.24`}, {8, 8}}, 
        {{26.6316`, 221.423`}, {9, 9}}};
outputList = {};

For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++,
  If[Length[list[[i]]] >= k,
    outputList = Append[outputList, list[[i]][[Length[list[[i]]]]]];
  ];
];

outputList
```

Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html) and [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html) are usually convenient for these types of things:

```
(* Select takes a function as second argument and picks element where it is True *)
Select[list, Length[#] >= 3 &][[All, -1]]

(* Cases takes a pattern as second argument and finds all matches
   optionally transforming each match according to a rule *)
Cases[list, l_List /; Length[l] >= 3 :> l[[-1]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know which one is generally faster?

Comment: @HStoley, `Select` is generally faster. Especially for larger `List`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
With[{k = 3},
  Pick[list, Unitize[Length /@ list - (k - 1)], 1][[All, -1]]
 ]
```

It's a bit faster than `Select` or `Cases`

```
parts = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, 10^5];
data = Internal`PartitionRagged[RandomReal[1, {Total[parts], 2}], parts];

With[{k = 3},
  l0 = Pick[data, Unitize[Length /@ data - (k - 1)], 1][[All, -1]]
  ] // timeAvg
(l1 = Select[data, Length[#] >= 3 &][[All, -1]]) // timeAvg
(l2 = Cases[data, l_List /; Length[l] >= 3 :> l[[-1]]]) // timeAvg

(* 0.0524018
   0.104487
   0.127854 *)

l0 == l1 == l2
(* True *)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will also work (k=3):

```
Last /@ Select[list, Length[#] >= 3 &]
```

It takes the last element of each sublist of the list returned by Select.